# set ant path to patch binary

Tags: ant, patch

I have this ant task

```
<patch patchfile="${basedir}/mypatch.patch" ignorewhitespace="true"/>
```

How can I specify where to look for the patch.exe that runs that task without having to set a windows enviroment variable pointing to it?

Comment: I had a look in the code from the task. It looks like the patch.exe must be on PATH or in ${basedir}